# Deserialize Dynamic API Response using Gson

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, okhttp, json-deserialization

I have API consumed in my Android App using Retrofit + OkHttp.
I'm using gson to deserialize json response. If HTTP error happen, the normal json response will be like this:

```
{
  "httpStatus": 401,
  "devMessage": "Invalid credentials",
  "message": "Invalid credentials"
}
```

Normally if I got HTTP error, I'll take error message from `message` field and show it to user. But, sometimes `message` field doesn't give clear error message. And the detailed error message provided in `data`->`fields` in dynamic field name like this:

```
{
  "httpStatus": 422,
  "devMessage": "The given data was invalid.",
  "message": "The given data was invalid.",
  "data": {
    "fields": {
      "user.phone": [
        "The user.phone field is required."
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Or

```
{
  "httpStatus": 422,
  "devMessage": "The given data was invalid.",
  "message": "The given data was invalid.",
  "data": {
    "fields": {
      "location.address": [
        "The location.address field is required."
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If error details exist i need to take detailed message from that field and show it as a clear error message to user. So for example, in the case above, i will show message inside
`data`->`fields`->`location.address`->`ERROR MESSAGE`

How to address this issue?

Comment: I am unable to figure out what the issue is here? 

If the error exist why can't you parse the json and fetch the error?

Comment: i'm not do parsing manually but use gson converter for retrofit so it can automatically map json object into the POJO

Comment: How about making `fields` a `Map<String, List<String>>`? Would this work for you?